# How to install React and ReactDom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I want to start learning React but how do I install it and then have the possibility to import.
I tried: 
`npm install react react-dom`
It download node_modules and package-lock.json but still it doesn't work.
Here is the code i tried 
index.js

```
    import React from "react"
    import ReactDom from "react-dom"

    ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello World</h1>, document.getElementByID('root'));
```

HTML Code
index.html

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
        <head>
           <meta charset="UTF-8">
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
           <script src="./js/underscore.js"></script>
           <script src="./js/backbone.js"></script>
           <script src="index.js"></script>
           <title>Document</title>
        </head>
        <body>
           <div id="root"></div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Use create-react-app

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement we can help with.

Comment: ReactDom in your import statement and ReactDOM.render doesn't match please modify that along with document.getElementById

Answer (score 3):

from react's documentation:

> Create React App is a comfortable environment for learning React, and
>   is the best way to start building a new single-page application in
>   React.

So I would suggest you start with create-react-app. Its a pre-made environment with everything set up so until you're ready you don't have to worry about it.

1. first run: `npx create-react-app my-app`

This will create a new folder in your current directory and inside it is a ready made react application.

2. Enter the directory by running `cd my-app`
3. and then run this command `npm start` to start your react app

If you don't know how to run commands, google "how to run console commands in windows/mac/linux".

Answer (score 1):

You have a spelling error in your code

```
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello World</h1>, document.getElementByID('root'));
```

Should be

```
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello World</h1>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Also change your `ReactDom` import to

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
```